# Error in brick(file.choose()) : could not find function "brick"

Tags: r, r-raster, netcdf4

I was trying to convert a dataset from netcdf to csv format using R. 
although I have installed 'raster and 'netcdf4' in R. 
but still it doesn't find nc.brick.

```
rm(list=ls())
library(raster)
library(ncdf4)
nc.brick <- brick(file.choose)
dim(nc.brick)
nc.df <- as.data.frame(nc.brick[[1]],xy=T)
head(nc.df)
write.csv(nc.df,file.choose())
test <- read.csv(file.choose())
```

Comment: Avoid the use `file.choose()` --- if you use the actual filenames you have a record of what you have done, and you can easily extend the script it to many files with a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Can you see the difference between your usage of `file.choose` in these two lines:

```
nc.brick <- brick(file.choose)
write.csv(nc.df,file.choose())
```

there's your problem.